# Angular how to pass optional constructor arguments skipping some

Tags: angular, typescript

My constructor in angular2 has a lot of parameters which are optional .Its like a search construct. When passing parameters , how can i say this parameters is this ? 
Suppose if there is first-name,last-name,age,sex which are all optional. I have to just pass sex without passing any other things. It looks like passing a parameter with a name. I dont want to pass null and by pass things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use one 'options' parameter:

```
const obj = new User({age: 28});
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score -2):

If its just a simple typescript class, all you have to do is add question marks after any optional parameters. So intead of

```
constructor(x: number, abc: string, z:number)
```

You could just do

```
constructor(x:number, abc?:string, z?:number)
```

Which would make the last two parameters optional.

If you're talking about making optional parameters in the constructor of a component, directive, or injectable service, you can import the "Optional" decorator and preface any injected classes with that. I.e :

```
constructor( @Optional() private win: WindowService) {
```

Comment: my question is about how to pass only few optional parameters

Comment: And that's exactly what my answer was about... ? What are you not understanding?

Comment: How can invoke the constructor by passing only Z without passing  x?

Comment: Oh. In typescript you have to specify "undefined" if there is a "gap" in your parameters list. The better thing to do would be to pass a single object as a parameter, and then create an interface for that object. 

     export interface MyInterface { 
        property1: number; 
        property2?: any;
        property3? number;
        property4: string;
     }

and then you can just pass the parameters you have available without having to specify if any are missing.  

     let abc = new MyClass({property1: 123, property5: "abc"});  and not have to worry about any in between.

Comment: I am looking for something like named parameters rather than undefined or null.